# Why ad-hoc network devices do not see each other?

Tags: wifi, network-interface, ad-hoc-network, iot, net

I have 3 devices. On one tetwork one device can see another, yet they both can not see the third one. They are in same wi-fi ad-hoc network. 2 of them see each other and one does not see no one. Devices are in cl.ose proximity (10cm). How to figure out why?

## For one That does not play with others:

Here is ifconfig:

```
root@edison:~# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:4b:87:a9:87:53
          inet addr:192.168.2.50  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7a4b:87ff:fea9:8753/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1528  Metric:1
          RX packets:1342297 errors:0 dropped:852312 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:158162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:80024954 (76.3 MiB)  TX bytes:10973582 (10.4 MiB)
```

Here is iwconfig:

```
root@edison:~# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"pi-ad-hoc"
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Cell: 3A:41:3D:F5:20:A2
          Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

Here is iwlist scan (strangly it shows **more then one network** with same name):

```
          Cell 01 - Address: 3A:41:3D:F5:20:A2
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-4 dBm
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"pi-ad-hoc"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Ad-Hoc
                    Extra:tsf=0000002153a8a359
                    Extra: Last beacon: 90ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000970692D61642D686F63
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
...

          Cell 06 - Address: 2E:5D:62:E8:17:46
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=0 dBm
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"pi-ad-hoc"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Ad-Hoc
                    Extra:tsf=00000021521e98ce
                    Extra: Last beacon: 25920ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000970692D61642D686F63
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
...
          Cell 08 - Address: 0A:27:49:3D:49:E9
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=0 dBm
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"pi-ad-hoc"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Ad-Hoc
                    Extra:tsf=0000002153313756
                    Extra: Last beacon: 7920ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000970692D61642D686F63
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
...
          Cell 09 - Address: E2:32:E6:6A:CC:A9
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=0 dBm
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"pi-ad-hoc"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Ad-Hoc
                    Extra:tsf=0000002153a96297
                    Extra: Last beacon: 40ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000970692D61642D686F63
```

Here is ping:

```
root@edison:~# ping 192.168.2.2
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.2.2 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
root@edison:~# ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1): 56 data bytes

^C
--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
root@edison:~#
```

## And here for the one of that do work:

ping:

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=8.13 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=6.99 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=7.80 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=7.39 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.998/7.584/8.138/0.441 ms
pi@pi3-2:~ $ ping 192.168.2.50
PING 192.168.2.50 (192.168.2.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.2.50 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7999ms
```

ifconfig:

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:67:07:fc
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ac7f:b393:aac1:78bf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1528  Metric:1
          RX packets:1287637 errors:0 dropped:158601 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:487835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:91775299 (87.5 MiB)  TX bytes:46478896 (44.3 MiB)
```

iwconfig

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"pi-ad-hoc"
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Cell: 3A:41:3D:F5:20:A2
          Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

iwlist wlan0 scan

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 3A:41:3D:F5:20:A2
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-35 dBm
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"pi-ad-hoc"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Ad-Hoc
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 154751220ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000970692D61642D686F63
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
                    IE: Unknown: 06020000
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD070050F202000100
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A21001FFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1604001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD09001018020010000000
```

Comment: Devices are raspberry pi3 x2 and intel Edison.

Comment: One common recommendation when running ad-hoc networks is to turn down power management with `iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Comment: Another thing I would try is creating the ad-hoc AP on the Edison and connecting both RPi boards to it.

Comment: for latest and greatest stuff for Intel Edison better to look here: https://github.com/edison-fw (and wiki: https://htot.github.io/meta-intel-edison/)